# following code failed to find sum of numbers between 1-20 when incremented by 3 using JavaScript? point out the mistake kindly

Tags: javascript, html

If I enter the value of x in the following code it works perfectly but as soon as I set it for user the code does not work I think I am missing something

```js
var x, z = 0;
x = prompt("enter a no. between 1-20");
while (x <= 20) {
  z = (x + z);
  x = x + 3;
}
document.write(z + "<br>");
```

Comment: What is input and expected output? Also use textContent of some container instead of document.write

Comment: `prompt` returns a string. you need to convert the string to a number first.

Comment: change to `x = +prompt("enter a no. between 1-20");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var x, z = 0;
x = parseInt(prompt("enter a no. between 1-20"), 10);
while (x <= 20) {
  z += x;
  x += 3;
}
document.querySelector('output').textContent = z;
```

```html
<output>
```

- Converts input to a string
- Uses an [output](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) tag to display results